# Can we create externs from a full .js file with Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, extern, google-closure-compiler

I'm wondering whether extern files for the Google closure compiler need to be written by hand. I have not seen anything about the possibility of generating those files from my .js files. It's quite a bit of work to create all the externs by hand and it is error prone too (i.e. wrong parameter definitions as it changes with time...)

So I was wondering whether there was a Linux tool (command line) for that purpose. If not, would there be a way to compare the .js against the extern files so I can at least make sure they are in sync.?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dotnetwise.com/Code/Externs/ aims to do this but I haven't used it myself so I'm not sure how well it works.

We have an issue open to [do this as part of the compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/175) but I don't expect that it will happen anytime soon.

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried Code/Externs/ and I guess that either I do not know how to use it or it does not understand namespaces. Also it looks like it would be a lot of manual labor! (Safer, but still... I'm actually looking for a command line tool)